# kernel module which will dump only modified heap page of a user process

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel-module, crash-dumps

Is there any way from a **kernel module to track which all page is written in heap** ,

when user application write to a malloced page( example like  given below ptr[1] =3) ?

**The real use of this is , i am writing a kernel module which will dump only modified heap page of the user process**

```
int main()
{
        char *ptr;
        ptr = malloc(10);

        ptr[1] =3;
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean `modified` heap page? And please note that `malloc` can use `brk` as well as `mmap`.

Comment: Modified i meant ,if we write some value into that page(ex ptr[1] =3)  or modify it again like ptr[1] = 12.Essentially from kernel module i want to check every write to that page

Comment: First of all, take a look at page fault handler. Next, learn how MMU works, i.e. how CPU and Linux manages page frames. Your task has a complex solution.